# When I click on the button to sign up in my app, nothing happens in FireBase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working in Android Studio for my study. I have created a social sports app.

Now I want to have a log in system and for that I followed youtube videos. I have a sign up screen where you can fill in full name, username, email and password.

Now when I click on the sign up button, my real time database in firebase does not updated.

I have tried many many things but nothing seems to work.

My rules in firebase are both on true

I don't get any errors except for one error that can be ignored as far as I can see on other posts. (E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1)

So here is my code:

[image: codepart1]

[image: codepart2]

[image: codepart3]

(I also define the other strings, but I think that was not necessary to show)

[image: codepart4]

Pleaseee can somebody help me, I have been working on this the last 5 hours and otherwise all my work for the sign up/log in screens are for nothing.

If there is some info/pictures/code missing, please let me know, I can send it immediately.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, do not post pictures of code and text.  Copy the code into the question itself and format it so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: I am sorry, thanks for commenting. I have send my project to a friend who also works on the project and for him it seems to work. Very strange. Difference between Mac and Windows maybe